# Grammar and/or lexer for Swift AST output

Tags: swift, abstract-syntax-tree

I've started a [project](https://github.com/palfvin/Swift2Kotlin) to transpile a subset of Swift into Kotlin (for sharing business logic between iOS and Android apps) and am using the Abstract Syntax Tree output of the Swift compiler (i.e. as produced by the `-dump-ast` option) as a starting point.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an "official" grammar and/or lexer for the AST output itself. It's not that complicated and I've created one myself for now, but I'd feel more comfortable if I was relying on something supported.

Comment: Looking for something similar. You are not alone. Please vote on [this bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7581).